# How to implement single sign on in Application hosted in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular6, single-sign-on, aws-api-gateway

I have created an application in Angular 6 and hosted in AWS S3 at the backend I have cloudfront API Gateway lambda Dynamo DB etc.

Now I have to integrate this with single sign on with this application.

Can someone help on how and where to implement this?

A small direction would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito user pool might be suitable for your requirement. Please refer : [Authenticate with Cognito user pools with SSO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-identity-pool)